# Manipulating a Denominator

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Perhaps I've just forgotten my basic maths, but how can I show the following

$$\large \frac{\frac{y^2+1}{y^3}x^5-x^4-x^2}{x-y}=\frac{y^2+1}{y^3}x^4+\frac{1}{y^2}x^3+\frac{1}{y}x^2$$

ensuring that $x$ does not appear in the denominator? Specifically, I'd like to see a sum of terms with only powers of y in the denominators.

Comment: $y$ appears only in the denominator !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Ah good spot, I missed something important. $y$ actually does appear in the numerator as it is a function of $a,b,c$. I will edit appropriately.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Ok I've changed the expression slightly, but this one will still answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be what you want.$$\begin{align}\frac{{\frac{y^2+1}{y^3}}x^5-x^4-x^2}{x-y}&=\frac{(y^2+1)x^5-y^3x^4-y^3x^2}{y^3(x-y)}\\&=\frac{x^2\{(y^2+1)x^3-y^3x^2-y^3\}}{y^3(x-y)}\\&=\frac{x^2\{x^2y^2(x-y)+x^3-y^3\}}{y^3(x-y)}\\&=\frac{x^2(x-y)(x^2y^2+x^2+xy+y^2)}{y^3(x-y)}\\&=\frac{x^2(x^2y^2+x^2+xy+y^2)}{y^3}\\&=\frac{x^4}{y^3}+\frac{x^3}{y^2}+\frac{x^2+x^4}{y}\end{align}$$

Comment: Yes I was getting similar. There was a mistake in the expression and I've also put in what I want to find.

Comment: @user13223423: Now I may get it. Don't change the expression several times...

Comment: It was simply a mistake, apologies

Comment: @user13223423: Ok, but my answer is different from what you wrote...I'll check my answer again.

Comment: I tried different values of $x$ and $y$ and my equality seems to hold.

Comment: @user13223423: My answer is correct. see W.A. Please check if your right-hand side is correct.http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28%28y%5E2%2B1%29%2F%28y%5E3%29%29x%5E5-x%5E4-x%5E2%29%2F%28x-y%29

Comment: Our expressions are the same, just slightly different.

Comment: @user13223423: Yeah! I didn't notice it. So done.